# Webapi Core 3.1 won't run MSB6006 "csc.exe" exited with code -2146232797

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

My project was working fine until I stop debugging and reopen again. When I click in the error it takes me to a folder Roslyn to the file `"Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets"` with the error at the line

```
 <!-- Condition is to filter out the _CoreCompileResourceInputs so that it doesn't pass in culture resources to the compiler -->
<Csc Condition="'%(_CoreCompileResourceInputs.WithCulture)' != 'true'"
```

I searched about it and it seems to be that the VS can't find the right compiler, but in all tutorials, it's possible to change in the app.config, well it's a core Project it doesn't have that file.

I tried to clean the project, delete the Obj and debug folders, reinstall the net Core 3.1, install a Target Core on the NuGet, and nothing.